# Need C# example for setting background color on WPF ListBoxItem using runtime values

Tags: c#, background, runtime, listboxitem, data-driven

There are a lot of people providing coloring answers with meta-data programming which works fine, for simple color changes.  But, most people really have a need to color based on data values in the model.  Can someone provide a c# example code fragment that does the same thing as

```
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" color="Red" />
```

and could be called in this context

```
    public class MyItem : ListBoxItem {

       public override void OnSelected( RoutedEventArgs e ) {
          base.OnSelected( e );
          Foreground = someBoolean ? Brushes.White: Brushes.Black;
          Code_To_Coerce_HighlightBrushKey_To_The_Correct_Color(Brushes.Red);
       }

       public override void OnUnSelected( RoutedEventArgs e ) {
          base.OnUnSelected( e );
          Foreground = someBoolean ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.Black;
          Code_To_Coerce_HighlightBrushKey_To_The_Correct_Color(SystemColors.WindowBrush);
       }
    }
```

This would be the most helpful.  Meta-data, XAML programming, of course, lets Microsoft recolor or "change" most things about your coloring with themes and OS platform changes.  But that doesn't work for apps which need to color each ListBoxItem differently, including selection background and foreground changes.

UPDATE:

It is possible to use the follow code

```
public class SiteDataItem : ListBoxItem {
    SiteInfo site;
    protected override void OnUnselected( RoutedEventArgs e ) {
        base.OnUnselected(e);
        Foreground = site.Enabled ? Brushes.Black : Brushes.Red;
        Style s = new Style(typeof(ListBox));
        theSiteList.Style = s;
    }

    protected override void OnSelected( RoutedEventArgs e ) {
        base.OnSelected(e);
        Foreground = site.Enabled ? Brushes.White : Brushes.White;
        if( site.Enabled == false ) {
            Style s = new Style(typeof(ListBox));
            s.Resources.Add(SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey, Brushes.Red);
            theSiteList.Style = s;
        }
    } 
}
```

to effect the style changes, on selection and deselection, programmaticly and get the desired behavior.  What I'm trying to understand now, is how to tie into XAML's triggers and properties to drive this kind of behavior from just having data in a listbox's model.

Comment: Don't create your own `ListBoxItem` derived class. remove all that. You don't need that. WPF has already a `Background` property in the `ListBoxItem` class and much more. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025(v=vs.110).aspx#when_to_write_a_new_control)

Comment: I need to set the background property based on the data in each ListBoxItem.  I.e. each item in the list will be a different color, and the foreground and background-selection colors need to be set appropriately.

Comment: my point still stands. Create a proper ViewModel for the items and eventually use `Style.Triggers` to trigger color changes based on underlying data. Learn MVVM before you ever write a single line of code in WPF. WPF is not winforms. read the MSDN documentation I just linked. That code is unnecessary. delete it.

Comment: I am asking for a reasonable illustration of this, because I can just as readily make this work with setting the Style of the ListBoxItem with an override of HighlightBrushKey when needed. Using more XAML at the top level, and throwing in properties to drive triggers seems like a lot of overhead.  I see that you have plenty of good expertise in this area, and I appreciate your insight.  Give me more details on exactly how to make the static data values in the list's items fire appropriate style triggers for the ListBoxItem to change it's style, as selection occurs.

Comment: @HighCore yes..please provide a answer with a good starting point source code and some links for the OP

Comment: It seems that @HighCore is perhaps busy with other things.  If anyone else can provide a more elaborate example of using XAML specified processing driving per list item highlighting/processing on selection that would be very much appreciated.  Pointers to examples with source are always the most helpful.  There's an inordinate number of examples of "all items the same" XAML.  And I grasp that. I need to be able to compare string values, evaluate mathematical relationships (<, >, !=), etc.